# Select rows with certain combination

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all let me give you guys the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d8bd/11

I've been working on this for a while and am facing some programmers (and writers) block.

This is a sample pseudo code of what I am trying to accomplish in MySQL:

```
Return all rows WHERE {
  (`to_user_id` = '27' AND `to_delete` >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 720 HOUR) )
      AND 
  (`from_user_id` = '27' AND `from_delete` >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 720 HOUR) )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this (using `OR` instead of `AND` between groups of conditions)?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM messages
 WHERE (to_user_id   = 27 AND `to_delete`   >= NOW() - INTERVAL 720 HOUR)
    OR (from_user_id = 27 AND `from_delete` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 720 HOUR)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8beb1/1)** demo

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I realized my pseudo code was missing a huge chunk of what I needed. I've created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17682449/1043817

Answer (score 1):

One issue you're having is your `to_delete` and `from_delete` fields are both `NULL` in your Fiddle example.  Therefore, they can never meet your `WHERE` criteria.

That apart, no need for parentheses if all of your operators are `AND`.  Perhaps you're looking for `OR` instead?

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I realize those fields contain NULL values I just wanted to show you a sample structure of my DB. I also realized my pseudo code was missing a huge chunk of what I needed. I've created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17682449/1043817