# Returning all rows with certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all let me give you guys the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d8bd/11

I've been working on this for a while and am facing some programmers (and writers) block.

This is a sample pseudo code of what I am trying to accomplish in MySQL:

```
Return all rows WHERE {
  IF `to_user_id` = '27' AND `to_delete` >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 720 HOUR) 
     RETURN to_delete as del_time, COUNT(*), MAX(subject),

      - OR -

  IF `from_user_id` = '27' AND `from_delete` >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 720 HOUR) )
     RETURN from_delete as del_time, COUNT(*), MAX(subject),
} GROUP BY thread_hash
```

I'm essentially building a private messaging system and this is the query that represents the trash bin. Rows with the same `thread_hash` represent a messages in a thread. When a user is deletes a thread from their inbox it sets all `to_delete` to `NOW()` for that particular `thread_hash`. When a user is deletes a thread from their sent-box it sets all `from_delete` to `NOW()` for that particular `thread_hash`.

The query I'm trying to build should return all rows if `to_user_id` = $user_id AND  `to_delete` has a value OR if `from_user_id` = $user_id AND  `from_delete` has a value, grouped by the `thread_hash`  (ie threads you've deleted from your inbox, or sent-box)

I hope I'm being clear here. Please let me know if I can clear anything else up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, a simple `UNION ALL` should do what you want;

```
SELECT MAX(del_time), COUNT(*) cnt, MAX(subject) subject FROM (
  SELECT to_delete del_time, thread_hash, subject
  FROM messages
  WHERE to_user_id = 27 AND `to_delete` >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 720 HOUR)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT from_delete del_time, thread_hash, subject
  FROM messages
  WHERE from_user_id = 27 AND `from_delete` >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 720 HOUR)
) a
GROUP BY thread_hash;
```

[The modified SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f86bc5/3).

Comment: Thanks, this worked very nicely. Can you also help me write a query based on this that selects either `to_user_id` or `from_user_id`, which ever is not '27' as a temporary column? I want to join a separate table that will pull the user's profile/information